# CSS JQuery Position Selector is null on IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I have a problem with my JQuery position() code.
The code works perfectly on Chrome/Firefox but fails on IE.

The JS code is:

```
function myFunc() {

var x = $("#menu li.active");
if (x == null)
  alert('x is null');
else  
  alert(x.position().left + " " + x.position().top);
}

$(document).ready(function() { myFunc(); });
```

And the HTML is:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="test.php"><span>Test 1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="test2.php"><span>Test 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Normal browsers returns the left and top values, and IE says:

> Message: 'position().left' is null or not an object

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of IE are you using?

Comment: I test your code using jsbin and works fine on IE8 and IE7: http://jsbin.com/aruza3. What JQuery version are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
The HTML header was:

```
<html dir="rtl">
```

And that's what caused the problem in my case. When I set to page to LTR it works also on IE.

Thanks.